# Disable "The application unexpectedly quit" message in OS X

Tags: macos, osx-lion

While working on my application it crashes a lot while in development. However I always receive the annoying dialog box on the next *Compilation » Build » Launch*

> The application unexpectedly quit while trying to restore its windows. Do you want to try to restore it's windows again?

I never want that ever. How can I make it never ask me this question?

This application is an art project in C++, so I do not have access to some of the normal Objective-C / foundation frameworks within it if that matters.

Comment: Have you tried quitting instead of killing it in the debugger/IDE?

Comment: I have, I command+q to quit the app by finger habit.

Comment: **See [macos - Prevent "<application> quit unexpectedly" message on sigquit - Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/105846/prevent-application-quit-unexpectedly-message-on-sigquit) for answers**

Answer (score 0):

In System Preferences > General, find the checkbox "Restore windows when quitting and re-opening apps" and uncheck it.  You may also be able to change this for the specific app (I expect it would be in its `Info.plist`).

Comment: I just checked, and I noticed I happened to already have that box checked. I can modify the Info.plist for the specific flag, that's a good idea, I will look back for a property I can set

Comment: Did you mean already unchecked?  If it's checked, then programs built for Lion will restore their settings.

Comment: I did mean that, my mistake. That box is not checked.

Comment: I was not able to locate any Info.plist keys related to window-restore. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/InfoPlistKeyReference.pdf

Comment: @Onedayitwillmake http://osxdaily.com/2011/08/01/turn-off-resume-per-app-in-mac-os-x-lion/